# Finding time complexity of relation T (n) =T (n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3) if n > 3

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, big-o, time-complexity, fibonacci

Somewhat similar to fibonacci sequence

Running time of an algorithm is given by

```
T (n) =T (n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3) if n > 3
```

= n otherwise the order of this algorithm is?

if calculated by induction method then

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)
```

Let us assume T(n) to be some function aⁿ
then aⁿ = a<sup>n-1</sup> + a<sup>n-2</sup> + a<sup>n-3</sup>
=> a³ = a² + a + 1

which give complex solutions also roots of above equation according to my calculations are

```
a = 1.839286755
a = 0.419643 - i ( 0.606291) 
a = 0.419643 + i ( 0.606291)
```

Now, how can I proceed further or is there any other method for this?

Comment: Have a look on [Tribonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers)

Comment: [Ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T+%28n%29+%3DT+%28n-1%29%2BT%28n-2%29%2BT%28n-3%29)

Comment: @Ani that was fantastic. God bless you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, when you have determined the roots of the characteristic equation, then the T(n) can be the linear combination of the powers of those Roots

```
T(n)=A1*root1^n+A2*root2^n+A3*root3^n
```

So I guess the maximum complexity here will be 
(maxroot)^n where maxroot is the maximum absolute value of your roots. So for your case it is ~ 1.83^n

Comment: Thanks a lot that solves my problem. My Sincere Apologies for late reply !

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic analysis is done for running times of programs which give us how the running time will grow with the input.

For Recurrence relations (like the one you mentioned), we use a two step process:

1. Estimate the running time using the recursion tree method.
2. Validate(Confirm) the estimate using the substitution method.

You can find explanation of these methods in any algorithm text (eg. Cormen).

Answer (score 0):

it can be aproximated like 3+9+27+......3^n     which is O(3^n)